# How do you compare structs for equality in C?

Tags: c, struct, equality

How do you compare two instances of structs for equality in standard C?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

C provides no language facilities to do this - you have to do it yourself and compare each structure member by member.

Comment: if the 2 structures variable are initialied with calloc or they are set with 0 by memset so you can compare your 2 structures with memcmp and there is no worry about structure garbage and this will allow you to earn time

Comment: @MOHAMED Comparing floating point fields with `0.0, -0.0 NaN` is a problem with `memcmp()`.  Pointers that differ in binary representation may point to the same location (e.g. DOS: seg:offset) and so are equal.  Some systems have multiple null pointers which compare equally.  Same for obscure `int` with -0 and floating point types with redundant encodings.  (Intel long double, decimal64, etc.)  These issues make no difference is `calloc()` used or not or padding.

Comment: @chux On *any* modern 32- or 64- bit system I know of, the only issue is with floating point.

Comment: In case you wonder why `==` is not working with structures (like me), please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995631/why-are-structs-not-allowed-in-equality-expressions-in-c

Comment: @Demi : Today.  The 10th commandment for C programmers is 'Thou shalt foreswear, renounce, and abjure the vile heresy which claimeth that “All the world’s a VAX” ... '.  Replacing this with "All the world's a PC" is not an improvement.

Comment: @MartinBonner Can you name a specific system that is still in use on which `memcmp` will not work, provided that the struct has neither padding (use `-Wpadded` to check this) or floating-point values?

Comment: @Demi  No.  But they have existed, and may again

Comment: If structure B is a copy of structure A, obtained through memcpy(), then it should be ok to compare them with memcmp(), because in both cases they are treated as binary objects. As long as B is not altered in any way, before the comparison. Even B = B should be avoided.

Comment: Better answers for why C doesn't do this (including string buffers and especially unions) are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179174

Answer (score 137):

You may be tempted to use `memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(struct foo))`, but it may not work in all situations. The compiler may add alignment buffer space to a structure, and the values found at memory locations lying in the buffer space are not guaranteed to be any particular value.

But, if you use `calloc` or `memset` the full size of the structures before using them, you **can** do a *shallow* comparison with `memcmp` (if your structure contains pointers, it will match only if the address the pointers are pointing to are the same).

Comment: Close, because it works on "almost all" compilers, but not quite. Check out 6.2.1.6.4 in C90: "Two values (other than NaNs) with the same object representation compare equal, but values that compare
equal may have different object representations."

Comment: What? Can anyone explain Steve's quotation?

Comment: Consider a "BOOL" field.  In terms of equality, any non-zero BOOL is equal to every non-zero BOOL value.  So while 1 and 2 may both be TRUE and therefore equal, memcmp will fail.

Comment: Note that for many systems, there are usually compiler qualifiers, such as __packed (two underscores, e.g. `typedef __packed struct`) that will prevent the compiler from adding alignment padding. This makes things *much* easier

Comment: @JSalazar Easier for you maybe, but much harder for the compiler and the CPU and thus also much slower. Why do you think compiler add padding in the first place? Certainly not to waste memory for nothing ;)

Comment: @SteveJessop Do you know of any (non-embedded) system where this actually happens?

Comment: @Demetri: for example the float values positive and negative zero compare equal on any IEEE float implementation, but they do not have the same object representation. So actually I should not have said it works on "almost all compilers", it will fail on any implementation that lets you store a negative zero. I was probably thinking of funny integer representations at the time I made the comment.

Comment: @Demetri: but many do contain floats, and the questioner asks "how do you compare structs", not "how do you compare structs that don't contain floats". This answer says you can do a shallow compare with `memcmp` provided that the memory was cleared first. Which is close to working but not correct. Ofc the question also doesn't define "equality", so if you take it to mean "byte-wise equality of the object representation" then `memcmp` does exactly that (whether the memory is cleared or not).

Comment: It's worth noting that a standard-compliant C compiler may not add padding to *the beginning* of a struct; only after members... and if a `struct X` contains the same initial sequence of elements as a `struct Y` then those elements are required to exist at the same offsets.

Comment: Also note that from a pedantic perspective, two objects with the same type and binary representation can still have different behavior in certain cases. I don't think any real world compiler takes advantage of this though.

Comment: if the structs contains pointers and each one is allocated with two different malloc calls then the pointer addresses will be different between the two structs and memcmp will fail.  There needs to be a mechanism that compares by value regardless of the type of the struct member

Comment: Initializing the struct with `memset`, etc is not enough to ensure the padding bits are still the same after writing to members of the struct, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52684192/689161

Comment: @SteveJessop if a and b is same struct type, then it will have the same padding, and same size.
why memcmp will be problematic ?
the padding will be empty bytes so it will be equal in both

Comment: @AtheelMassalha *the padding will be empty bytes so it will be equal in both*  That is not true.  Any padding contains indeterminate values that can't reliably be compared to anything.

Answer (score 25):

If you do it a lot I would suggest writing a function that compares the two structures.  That way, if you ever change the structure you only need to change the compare in one place.

As for how to do it.... You need to compare every element individually

Comment: I would write a separate function even if I were to use it only once.

Answer (score 23):

You can't use memcmp to compare structs for equality due to potential random padding characters between field in structs.

```
  // bad
  memcmp(&struct1, &struct2, sizeof(struct1));
```

The above would fail for a struct like this:

```
typedef struct Foo {
  char a;
  /* padding */
  double d;
  /* padding */
  char e;
  /* padding */
  int f;
} Foo ;
```

You have to use member-wise comparison to be safe.

Comment: Unlikely to be padding after the double; the char will be perfectly adequately aligned immediately after the double.

Answer (score 11):

@Greg is correct that one must write explicit comparison functions in the general case.

It is possible to use `memcmp` if:

- the structs contain no floating-point fields that are possibly `NaN`.
- the structs contain no padding (use `-Wpadded` with clang to check this) OR the structs are explicitly initialized with `memset` at initialization.
- there are no member types (such as Windows `BOOL`) that have distinct but equivalent values.

Unless you are programming for embedded systems (or writing a library that might be used on them), I would not worry about some of the corner cases in the C standard.  The near vs. far pointer distinction does not exist on any 32- or 64- bit device.  No non-embedded system that I know of has multiple `NULL` pointers.

Another option is to auto-generate the equality functions.  If you lay your struct definitions out in a simple way, it is possible to use simple text processing to handle simple struct definitions.  You can use libclang for the general case – since it uses the same frontend as Clang, it handles all corner cases correctly (barring bugs).

I have not seen such a code generation library.  However, it appears relatively simple.

However, it is also the case that such generated equality functions would often do the wrong thing at application level.  For example, should two `UNICODE_STRING` structs in Windows be compared shallowly or deeply?

Comment: Explicitly initializing the structs with `memset`, etc. does not guarantee the value of the padding bits after further writing to a struct element, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52684192/689161

Answer (score 4):

Note you can use memcmp() on non static stuctures without
worrying about padding, as long as you don't initialise
all members (at once). This is defined by C90:

http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/auto_init.html

Comment: Is it actually specified that `{0, }` will also zero any padding bytes?

Comment: GCC at least zeroes padding bytes for partially initialized structs as demonstrated at the link above, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056364/is-zero-initialization-of-structures-guaranteed-to-wipe-padded-areas details that C11 specifies that behavior.

Comment: Not very useful in general, because all padding becomes indeterminate upon assigning to any member

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether the question you are asking is:

1. Are these two structs the same object?
2. Do they have the same value?

To find out if they are the same object, compare pointers to the two structs for equality.
If you want to find out in general if they have the same value you have to do a deep comparison. This involves comparing all the members. If the members are pointers to other structs you need to recurse into those structs too.

In the special case where the structs do not contain pointers you can do a memcmp to perform a bitwise comparison of the data contained in each without having to know what the data means.

Make sure you know what 'equals' means for each member - it is obvious for ints but more subtle when it comes to floating-point values or user-defined types.

Answer (score 2):

`memcmp` does not compare structure, `memcmp` compares the binary, and there is always garbage in the struct, therefore it always comes out False in comparison.

Compare element by element its safe and doesn't fail.

Comment: if the 2 structures variable are initialied with calloc or they are set with 0 by memset so you can compare your 2 structures with memcmp and there is no worry about structure garbage and this will allow you to earn time

Comment: calloc or memset will not help you, as every assignment returns the padding bytes to indeterminate values

Comment: No, there is not always garbage. Padding is done only when it is needed. Some structures may be safely compared using memcmp.

Answer (score 0):

If the structs only contain primitives or if you are interested in strict equality then you can do something like this:

```
int my_struct_cmp(const struct my_struct * lhs, const struct my_struct * rhs)
{
    return memcmp(lhs, rsh, sizeof(struct my_struct));
}
```

However, if your structs contain pointers to other structs or unions then you will need to write a function that compares the primitives properly and make comparison calls against the other structures as appropriate.

Be aware, however, that you should have used memset(&a, sizeof(struct my_struct), 1) to zero out the memory range of the structures as part of your ADT initialization.

Answer (score -2):

if the 2 structures variable are initialied with calloc or they are set with 0 by memset so you can compare your 2 structures with memcmp and there is no worry about structure garbage and this will allow you to earn time

Answer (score -3):

This compliant example uses the #pragma pack compiler extension from Microsoft Visual Studio to ensure the structure members are packed as tightly as possible:

```
#include <string.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct s {
  char c;
  int i;
  char buffer[13];
};
#pragma pack(pop)

void compare(const struct s *left, const struct s *right) { 
  if (0 == memcmp(left, right, sizeof(struct s))) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: That is indeed correct. But in most cases you do not want your structs to be packed!

Quite a lot of instructions, and pointers, require that the input data is word-aligned. If it's not, then the compiler needs to add extra instructions to copy and re-align data before the actual instruction can be executed. If the compiler would not re-align the data the CPU will throw an exception.