# Default value of an Objective-C struct and how to test

Tags: c, objective-c, struct, default-value

I'm trying to test if a property has been set yet. I know that with objects that I've got:

```
CGRect ppGoalFrame;
LocalPlaySetup *localPlaySetup;
```

and I can test

```
if (localPlaySetup == nil)
```

but if I attempt to test the CGRect with == nil or == NULL

```
if (ppGoalFrame == nil)
```

I get

```
invalid operands to binary == (have 'CGRect' and 'void *')
```

So is the `CGRect` "void", null, nil...? before it's set? Obviously I can't compare CGrect to a void pointer (I can't use `ppGoalFrame == void`); is there another way to test this? The Objective-C so far is pretty easy to understand but as soon as the C looms, I get a bit lost.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Only pointers can be null.  CGRect is a struct - it represents a contiguous block of memory.  The only way to tell if it has been set it to check its contents.

Apple does provide a constant `CGRectNull`.  You could set your variable to this and use the CGRectIsNull function to determine if it has been set.  `CGRectNull` is not the same as `CGRectZero` so you need not worry if the desired value is zero.

Note that CGRectNull simply contains a CGRect struct filled with values that Apple can later identify for the CGRectIsNull function.  It is not the same null as when comparing pointers.

Comment: Ended up using CGRectIsEmpty to test. Don't have to set them in any way. Your answer got me on the right track though, so thanks.

Answer (score 45):

All instance variables in an Objective-C class are initialized to zero.  So all pointers are `nil`, numbers are 0, and structs are zeroed.  Since the CGRect is a plain struct, it will be initialised to `origin.x=0, origin.y=0, size.width=0, size.height=0`.

So to test if your `CGRect` has been set, you need to compare it (by value) to zero.  The `CGRectIsEmpty` function will do exactly this:

```
if (CGRectIsEmpty(ppGoalFrame))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 great answer. You could edit it to use `CGRectIsEmpty` IMO.

Comment: Thanks @gavinb, that's great. Personally I'd delete the reference `CGRectEqualToRect`, as it's now "legacy code".

Answer (score 5):

From `CGGeometry.h`:

```
/* Return true if `rect' is empty (that is, if it has zero width or height),
   false otherwise. A null rect is defined to be empty. */
```

an empty rectangle is one that has no area, where on or both sides are zero.
Use instead:

```
CGRect newRect = CGRectNull;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal "nothing" value. There's `nil` for objects and `NULL` for pointers, but there's no equivalent for plain value types — they always have *some* value, even if it's just nonsense. You can take an arbitrary value and say "I'm going to call this the null value for this type" (say, `#define IntNull 4444444` and hope some calculation never accidentally returns that value), but there's no real null value.

In the case of CGRect in particular, Apple used the "pick an arbitrary value" tactic and defined `CGRectNull`, but CGRect variables aren't set to that by default — you have to specifically set it yourself. By default, CGRect instance variables are set to `CGRectZero`, but remember that this is just a normal CGRect struct at location (0,0) with 0 width and 0 height. And local CGRects in a function have a totally unpredictable value.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap CGRect in NSValue too:

`[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)]`

And then avoid the `nil` value.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is an obvious and elegant solution (lol):

`SomeStruct someStruct = {0};`

Which just fills all the "elements" of the struct with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do a binary comparison of a C structure, which is [what CGRect is](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/c/cgrect-cgsize-and-cgpoint.html).  A quick Google search and checking the C For Dummies Desk Reference didn't turn anything up.  You could declare CGRect ppGoalFrame, initialize the members of the structure with default values (if they're not already), and test the structure members.

Update Edit: This [question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141720/how-do-you-compare-structs-for-equality-in-c) for C structures.

Comment: The story is different for Objective-C when discussing instance variables.

Comment: @gavinb: Maybe. I'm still brushing up on my C before I plunge into Objective-C.