# Comparing true color pixels in C

Tags: c

this is my first question here; hope I'll be clear enough...

I've got this struct available

```
typedef struct COLORTRIPLE
{
  byte blue;
  byte green;
  byte red;
}
```

which is contained in another struct like that:

```
struct color_temp
{ 
  COLORTRIPLE color;
  int temp;
};
```

And (EDIT)

```
#define PIXEL(image, row, column)  \
    image.pixel [(row) * image.width + (column)]
```

is a macro.

So there will be `PIXEL(bmpin,row,column).red, PIXEL(bmpin,row,column).green and PIXEL(bmpin,row,column).blue`.

I need to scan a bitmap file pixel by pixel and check if the current pixel is equal to one color of the color_temp struct.

I tried something like:

```
if ((PIXEL(bmpin,row,column))==(map[n].color))
{...}
```

where

```
struct color_temp map[]
```

is a vector of color_temp.

But cygwin gcc says:

```
error:request for member 'color' in something not a struct or a union
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Is it C or C++? There is a difference you know.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Next time please format your code using the `101010` button above the edit box, as Naveen meanwhile has done for you. Also, if this is a homework question, please add the `homework` tag. (It prompts people to post answers that help you learning instead of snippets you can turn in as your own.) Then, decide whether your code and question is C or C++. Besides some syntactical similarities, these two have very little in common. And if you reply to comments, don't forget to properly @address people, so the replies show up in their "Aswers" tab. And please read the FAQ.

Comment: If `PIXEL(...)` is a pointer, then `PIXEL(...).red` is bad code. What is `PIXEL`, a macro?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "doesn't work"? Does it not compile (What's the error?), fall over at runtime, or something else?

Comment: thanks for the replies and sorry for the mistakes, now I'll edit the message

Comment: @Williham Totland: I tried that before posting my question and the compiler gives me the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int is_pixels_equal (COLORTRIPLE a, COLORTRIPLE b) {
  return (a.red == b.red && a.green == b.green && a.blue == b.blue);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "are_pixels_equal()"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly compare structs in C, it doesn't define such an operator. Therefore you have to implement it yourself, as Williham Totland suggested. For more discussion, see for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141720/how-do-you-compare-structs-for-equality-in-c).