# Initializing a struct with another struct

Tags: c, struct, copy

How do I assign a value from struct to another. Here is my code.

I believe I am assigning the address of the struct which is what I don't want to do. I want to assign the values of "temp" to 'a'. I commented the section I need help on. Thanks

Also off-topic.. How do I post code without having to indent myself every line, line-by-line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

typedef struct dynArrStruct
{
    double value1;
    int value2;
    int value3;
}dynArr;


void init(dynArr* a)
{
    dynArr temp;
    temp.value1 = (double)(rand()) * rand() / rand();
    temp.value2 = rand()%100;
    temp.value3 = rand()%1000;
    printf("In init(): value1: %14.5f, value2: %6d, value3: %6d\n",
            temp.value1, temp.value2, temp.value3);
    a = &temp;  // THIS LINE
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    dynArr a1[SIZE];
    dynArr* a2[SIZE];

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        init(&(a1[i]));
        init(a2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: select all code lines using mouse and then ctrl-k

Comment: You have a potential undefined behavior in your code, if you copy to a pointer that haven't been initialized, as is the case with the `a2` array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy struct to struct in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127246/copy-struct-to-struct-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use assignment (assuming `a` is pointing to valid memory):

```
*a = temp;
```

Note this works because the members of the `struct` are not pointers.  Using this technique (or `memcpy()`) on a `struct` that contained member pointers would result in both `struct`s having members pointing to the same address, which may be dangerous (possibly resulting in dangling pointers). If a `struct` contains pointers then a deep copy of the `struct` is required (allocating memory for the member pointers and copying the pointed to objects in the source struct to the allocated memory in the destination `struct`).

Also, in this case `temp` is superfluous and you just assign values directly to the members of `a`.

Comment: That was the fix I needed for a1. Thanks. Now a2 is seg faulting and not even storing

Answer (score 2):

```
void init(dynArr* a)
{
    dynArr temp;
    temp.value1 = (double)(rand()) * rand() / rand();
    temp.value2 = rand()%100;
    temp.value3 = rand()%1000;
    printf("In init(): value1: %14.5f, value2: %6d, value3: %6d\n",
            temp.value1, temp.value2, temp.value3);
    a = &temp;  // THIS LINE
}
```

`temp` is a local variable with automatic storage duration. It ceases to exist when `init` returns.

Fortunately, the pointer `a` that is made to point to `temp` also ceases to exist, so `init` doesn't create dangling pointers for your programme.

`struct`s are assignable, so if the argument points to valid memory, you can just initialise the pointee with

```
*a = temp;
```

That would be okay for

```
init(&(a1[i]));
```

since `&a1[i]` points to allocated memory, but not for

```
init(a2[i]);
```

since `a2[i]` is an uninitialised pointer.

If you want to allocate memory in `init`, you'd have to pass a `dynArr**`, but then you can't use it for the first case. So you ought to allocate memory to `a2[i]` before calling `init` for the second case.