# sizeof vs sizeof() in standard C?

Tags: c, sizeof

I saw some code which used sizeof  directly and wondered if it is standard C. To my surprise, it was working just fine. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char buff[255];
   printf("size %d\n", sizeof buff);
   return 0;
}

Output: size 255
```

As you can see, in the above example I used `sizeof <variable>` instead of `sizeof(<variable>)`

Please throw more light on it.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. You can use both variants.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the question is perfectly answered already

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"When sizeof's operand is a type, it has to be enclosed in parentheses. But when sizeof's operand is a variable, this is not required."--Expert C Programming: Deep C secrets. And from c11 standard:

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

Comment: @Jongware: Absolutely! I have edited the answer to cite it. Thank you for pointing it out.