# Is zero initialization of structures guaranteed to wipe padded areas?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned field1 :1;
    unsigned field2 :1;
    unsigned field3 :1;
} mytype;
```

The first 3 bits will be usable but `sizeof(mytype)` will return `4` which means 29 bits of padding.
My question is, are these padding bits guaranteed by the standard to be zero initialized by the statement:

```
mytype testfields = {0};
```

or:

```
mytype myfields = {1, 1, 1};
```

Such that it's safe to perform the following `memcmp()` on the assumption that bits 4..29 will be zero and therefore won't affect the comparison:

```
if ( memcmp(&myfields, &testfields, sizeof(myfields)) == 0 )
    printf("Fields have no bits set\n");
else
    printf("Fields have bits set\n");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes and no. The actual standard, C11, specifies:

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not
> initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - ....
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)
>   according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

So this only holds for objects of static storage, at a first view. But then later it says in addition:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
> are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
> string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
> are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
> initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
> duration.

So this means that padding inside sub-structures that are not initialized explicitly is zero-bit initialized.

In summarry, some padding in a structure is guaranteed to be zero-bit initialized, some isn't. I don't think that such a confusion is intentional, I will file a defect report for this.

Older versions didn't have that at all. So with most existing compilers you'd have to be even more careful, since they don't implement C11, yet. But AFAIR, clang already does on that behalf.

Also be aware that this only holds for initialization. Padding isn't necessarily copied on assignment.

Comment: I think you should add the beginning of the C11 paragraph *If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:* This does not guarantee the padding in `mytype testfields = {0};` is set to `0`.

Comment: @ouah, in fact there seems to be a loophole, you are right. I don't think that it is intended, so I will explain that a bit more. Good point.

Comment: Regarding the paragraph you added *If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list [...]* my understanding from the wording is it concerns only the remainder *members* of the aggreate, not the padding. But it also means the remainder aggregate members of an aggregate will have their padding zeroed.

Comment: @ouah, exactly. I find this quite anoying and I have now written more on it in https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/c11-defects-initialization-of-padding/

Answer (score 6):

The C99 standard doesn't specify the padding bits would be set to zero. In fact, it specifically mentions that the values of any padding bits are unspecified, so that padding need not be copied in an assignment.

Footnote 51 to 6.2.6.1 (6) (n1570):

> Thus, for example, structure assignment need not copy any padding bits.

The new C2011 standard - thanks to [Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) for sharing that knowledge - specifies that padding bits in objects of static or thread storage duration without explicit initialisation are initialised to 0.

There are still no guarantees for assignment.

Comment: Hmm, that rather suggests that `memcmp()` would be an unsafe way to compare any structure that has padding in it though wouldn't it?

Comment: @Benj Yes, `memcmp` is not safe due to padding effect. Although the padded bits are unused, you *legally* don't have access to it. So, it shouldn't matter either way whether standard mandates the padding or not.

Comment: @KingsIndian: If the memory was received via `calloc()` or other such means, one does have legitimate access to it.  On the other hand, I believe that almost any operation on a structure is allowed to do anything it likes with any padding therein.  Code may legitimately use a pointer to a struct to copy all the bytes therein if it does not access the struct in the meantime, but the only guarantee the system would make regarding the padding bytes would be that their value in the source structure would not cause problems in the destination.

Comment: @DanielFischer, this changed with C11. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, are these padding bits guaranteed by the standard to be zero initialized by the statement:

No.

The value of the padding is unspecified:

> (C99, 6.2.6.1p6) "When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values"

**EDIT:** See Jens Gustedt [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13056569/1119701), C11 now guarantees the padding is set to `0` in (rare) certain circumstances