# reading and writing in the padding bits of a structure

Tags: c++, casting, padding, undefined-behavior

I have the following 32 bit aligned structure with the necessary padding to ensure 32 bit alignment of the `i32` data member:

```
struct
{
    std::uint8_t  i8; 
    std::uint32_t i32;
} x, y = {0};
```

Is writing in the padding bits has a well defined behavior? For instance, in the code:

```
reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t&>(x) = 256u;
```

is the padding part *always* written and read as 1?

Another question:

Is the padding *always* initialized to 0 for `y`?

I understand so as C++ **[dcl.init]** states:

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means: if T is a
>   non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class
>   subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits

However, I'm not seeing this behavior in Microsoft compiler (vc++ v120), example:

```
reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t&>(y) == 0u
```

doesn't evaluate to `true`. It could be a missing feature or I misunderstood the phrase from the standard.

Comment: `y` is not zero-initialized in that case, it's value-initialized.  The initialization rules are super unintuitive and confusing.

Comment: That being said, I came here to find the answer to that first part of your question :(  Sad that there's no answer here

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in padding but I don't believe it is possible to guarantee any padding, at least not without special and possibly implementation-specific options.

It is not defined behavior to use reinterpret_cast for anything other than to convert back to the original pointer. reinterpret_cast means you are doing something dodgy in your code.

This question talks about what padding is initialized to
[Is zero initialization of structures guaranteed to wipe padded areas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056364/is-zero-initialization-of-structures-guaranteed-to-wipe-padded-areas)

Comment: I don't think he wants to guarantee that padding exists so much as not have undefined behavior IF padding exists.