# error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'struct demo' and 'struct demo')

Tags: c, arrays, struct, compiler-errors, equality

Code 1:

```
struct demo
{
    int a;
}d[2];

int main()
{
    d[0].a=5;
    d[1]=d[0];
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine

Code 2:

```
struct demo
{
    int a;
}d[2];

int main()
{ 
    d[0].a=5;
    d[1]=d[0];
    if(d[0]==d[1])
    {
        printf("hello");
    }
return 0;
}
```

This code gives error

```
error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'struct demo' and 'struct demo')
```

Why this error is coming in Code 2 ?

Comment: You can't compare arbitrary structs with `==`, write your own comparison function or use `memcmp`.

Comment: @Barmar why all this talk of `memcmp` in those answers? I don't get it, struct's can have padding which we can't know the value of. The other linked answer to, so weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compare the members of the struct yourself, like this:

```
if(d[0].a ==d[1].a)
```

structs are not valid operands for equality(`==`), the operands have to be an arithmetic type or a pointer. We can see this from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.9` *Equality operators*:

> One of the following shall hold:

- both operands have arithmetic type
- both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
- one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a
  qualified or unqualified version of void; or
- one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

Answer (score 6):

C has no support for struct comparison. You have to compare the struct yourself by comparing all members one by one.

[How do you compare structs for equality in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141720/how-do-you-compare-structs-for-equality-in-c)