# bcmp() returns 1 though the blocks are similar

Tags: c, compare

I am doing a `bcmp(&v6_addr1,&v6_addr2,sizeof(v6_addr1))`

```
(gdb) p v6_addr2
$15 = {u = {b = "0\001", '\000' <repeats 12 times>, "\002\061", w = {304, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12546}, l = {304, 0, 0, 822214656}}}

(gdb) p v6_addr1
$16 = {u = {b = "0\001", '\000' <repeats 12 times>, "\002\061", w = {304, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12546}, l = {304, 0, 0, 822214656}}}

(gdb) p bcmp(&v6_addr1,&v6_addr2,sizeof(v6_addr1))
$18 = 1
```

The blocks seem to be same in gdb

but the bcmp return value is 1.. What could be the reason ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the struct contains padding, the values at those places could differ. This won't show up in a debugger if you inspect the values, because it only shows the values.

You can verify this by [examining](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html) the actual memory contents.

Don't `bcmp`. From the manual:

> The bcmp() function compares the two *byte sequences* s1 and s2 of length n each.

See this for a solution: [How do you compare structs for equality in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141720/how-do-you-compare-structs-for-equality-in-c)