# Generic array searcher and padding

Tags: c, arrays, generic-programming

I've been trying to implement a generic array searcher and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141720/how-do-you-compare-structs-for-equality-in-c#answer-141791) answer, which made me think that my implementation is only valid for dynamically allocated arrays.

The implementation looks like this:

```
void *array_search( void *arr,
                    size_t elem_size,
                    size_t len,
                    arr_search_checker v,
                    void *match)
{
    char *p = arr;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if(v((void *) p, match))
            return p;
        p += elem_size;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

The type `arr_search_checker`:

```
typedef bool (*arr_search_checker)(void *, void *);
```

Having a simple structure:

```
struct test_struct { int i; char c; };
```

And a check function:

```
bool test_checker(void *l, void *r)
{
    struct test_struct *ls = l, *rs = r;
    return ls->i == rs->i && ls->c == rs->c;
}
```

And `array` of length `len` which is an array of `struct test_struct` one can invoke the searcher:

```
struct test_struct match = { .i = 5, .c = 'A' };
struct test_struct *res = array_search(array,
    sizeof(struct test_struct), len, test_checker, &match);
```

Is that true that this implementation of `array_search` is only valid for dynamically allocated arrays because of incrementation of the char pointer `p` by size of the single element in the array what can be dangerous for padded arrays? Or is it totally invalid?

Comment: This question is more about suggestions on how to improve, or how to implement than a specific problem you are having and what you tried to fix it.  I believe It would really be a better fit for _[code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)_.

Answer (score 0):

Please state your question in the question topic.
The function array_search as valid for any arrays (don't know why dynamically allocated arrays are particular in any way). Char pointer p is incremented by `elem_size`. `elem_size` is assigned the value of `sizeof(struct test_struct)` in your example and that's perfectly ok. Padding has nothing to do with it. Imagine `struct test_struct` has some padding bytes added to it (anywhere, at the end of the structure or between any of it members). Then `sizeof(struct test_struct)` will be the size of the test_struct structure including the padding bytes, and p will still be increment correctly.
You may convert any pointer to `void*` and any pointer to `char*` without braking the strict aliasing rule. You cannot do arithmetic on `void*` pointers, that's why it gets converted to `char*` pointer. `elem_size` represents the size of a single array element in bytes, char represents one byte in memory, by doing `p += elem_size;` you add `elem_size` bytes to p (I like the form `p = &p[elem_size];`). The smallest addressable size in C is one byte (remember that byte may not be 8 bits) and the size of every structure or type in C must be an integral value (ie. `sizeof(struct test_struct)` cannot return 1,5).
For more, look at [bsearch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch) and [qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) functions from standard C library. They have a very similar declaration to `array_search` and work with any array types, just like `array_search` here.